# How can I get 10 entries from a database, ordered by score, given a starting position, using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to create a leaderboard service for a game. I have a database where I store the players with an ID(PK), a userName (unique) and a score. I'm trying to interrogate this database so that, given a player, I get it and the next 9 players in the list (or, if there aren't enough players, the last 10 players, since the one I want is guaranteed there). This is the code I have for getting the list:

```
var asyncPlayers = await (context.Players
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Score) 
                    .Skip(skip).Take(10)) 
                    .ToListAsync();
```

The problem is that I don't know how to determine 'skip' without returning the entire database, ordering it and finding it's position. Any way I can do this without getting the entire database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following documentation about [how to get index in linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) we can play with indexes.

First, an image for skip and take in every case or current player, ordered descending by points:

[image: take and skip]

And finaly code (not tested, maybe it has some typing error):

```
var numberToGet = 3;        //  Nubmers of recors to get
var currentPlayerId = 34;   //  current player id or other field

//  All players ordered by score descending
var allPlayersOrderByScore =
    context.Players
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.Score) 
        .Select((player, index) =>
            new { player = player, index = index }
        );

var allPlayersOrderByScoreCount = 
    allPlayersOrderByScore.Count();

//  Get current player from previous list, by id or other field
var currentPlayer = 
    allPlayersOrderByScore
    .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.player.PlayerId = currentPlayerId)

//  Check if not null
if(currentPlayer!=null){

    var currentPlayerIndex = currentPlayer.index;   

    if(allPlayersOrderByScoreCount-currentPlayerIndex >= numberToGet){
        //  GREEN, "normal case"
        var list = 
            allPlayersOrderByScore
            .Skip(currentPlayerIndex)
            .Take(numberToGet)
    }else{
        //  YELLOW, "anormal case"
        var skip = allPlayersOrderByScoreCount-numberToGet;
        var list = 
            allPlayersOrderByScore
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(numberToGet)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's a pretty good solution! With my old version, you loose some entries in case the score is the same, which this solves. (how are entries ordered in this case?) I still need to find a way to get 10 entries is the score is at the bottom of the list.

Comment: what confusing for me.... is your table with the entries in a specific order... aka if the player you want and its position in the database is important means that you have structured you entries in a very specific order. what happen if you remove that play and add back, adding back will put it as the last entry. is this your current design?

Comment: You order the table by points and then set the index acording this order... The position in database doesn't matter, look `allPlayersOrderByScore ` variable and the query

Comment: surely it would make more sense to just group the data... your interested in, like if you wanting x player and all his team mates.... that would make more sense right. Or! is it that you want it by score but to always including the selected player.... if that's the case the simplest way... without! creating ranks or complicating the  query... would just to get players ordered by score (trim if you want say top 10)..... then separately get the player you want and then just append to list... that so much easier..., that way you only fetch what you need and its simple.

Comment: Read this: `I'm trying to interrogate this database so that, given a player, I get it and the next 9 players in the list (or, if there aren't enough players, the last 10 players, since the one I want is guaranteed there)`

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work by interrogating the database again if there are less than 10 entries (which shouldn't happen that often compared to the regular case) before I saw your edit. I'll take a look later on at what you did.

Answer (score 0):

unsure if i understand correctly, but if i do...

```
var player = _db.Players.GetbyName("john smith");
var topPlayers = _db.Players.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Score).skip(0).Take(9);

///NB check if already in list.
var payerPlusOtherScoreplayers = topPlaters.Add(player).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Score)
```

would this not work?